# Не получается сделать так чтобы бот ТГ работал постоянно. Запускаю файл через папку с кодом main.py, открывается код в редакторе VScode

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот

**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**

[image: хочу чтобы тг бот работал постоянно,но он работает мин 5 после написания команды в VScode (python main.py) открываю редактор для запуска через файл main.py в чем проблема не понимаю ПОЖАЛУЙСТА опишите как решить эту проблему подробно!]

Comment: Чтобы бот работал "постоянно" - запускайте свой скрипт как сервис/процесс, но при этом ваш компьютер всегда должен оставаться включенным. Если не хотите "жертвовать" компьютером для этих целей, то ищите бесплатные/платные хостинги и там разворачивайте своего бота. А так, чтобы в VS Code запустить код, закрыть программу/выключить компьютер и при этом бот будет продолжал работать - это так не работает, кто-то же должен выполнять ваш код

Comment: спасибо теперь буду знать )

Comment: Удалите скриншот с токеном вашего бота. Скриншот замените на ```вставку кода (без токена)```

Answer (score 1):

Купите vps с ос linux и разверните его там [ссылка на статью](https://ramziv.com/article/38) ,либо разверните бота на heroku там дают 500 бесплатных часов.

Comment: еще можно простого бота развернуть в Google Apps Script ))